# #include confusion

Tags: c++

in order to avoid an include circle, I have replaced an #include that was previously in a classes header into its cpp file. I then placed a forward declaration into the header.

This solved my problem, however, the source file no longer seems to be able to access the members of the included file in the cpp file. Why is this? and what is the solution?

EDIT - real code below:

header:

```
#ifndef BULLET_H
#define BULLET_H

#include "BoundingSphere.h"
#include "helperMethods.h"

class GameObject;

class Bullet : public GameObject
{
private:
float velocity;
float distance;
D3DXVECTOR3 firedFrom;
BoundingSphere bSphere;

public:
Bullet(D3DXVECTOR3 position, D3DXVECTOR3 rotation, float velocity, D3DXCOLOR     colour);
BoundingSphere BulletSphere();//change this to simply use position
void Update();
};

#endif
```

source:

```
#include "Bullet.h"
#include "GameObject.h"

Bullet::Bullet(D3DXVECTOR3 position, D3DXVECTOR3 rotation, float velocity, D3DXCOLOR colour) 
: bSphere(BoundingSphere(position, 0.01f))
{
//Model = content.Load<Model>("Models\\basicMesh");
//Texture = content.Load<Texture2D>("Textures\\basicMesh");

distance = 0.0f;

Scale(D3DXVECTOR3(0.25f, 0.1f, 0.1f));// error

Colour(colour); //error

firedFrom = position;

Rotation() = rotation; // error
this->velocity = velocity;
}

BoundingSphere Bullet::BulletSphere()
{
return bSphere;
}

void Bullet::Update()
{
Position(D3DXVECTOR3Helper.PointOnXYCircle(firedFrom, distance, Rotation().z)); //error
bSphere.Centre(Position());
distance += velocity;
}
```

The first error is GameObject: base class undefined.

all the subsequent errors are "Error: Identifier "whatever" is undefined. They are all getters that are public and in gameobject.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must be getting a compiler error beforehand, forward declaration does not allow you to inherit from a class. Please post your code.

The following line:

```
class Bullet : public GameObject
```

means you have to include `GameObject.h` in `Bullet.h`. Again, a forward declaration is not sufficient for inheritance. If you get more errors, post the exact error code, text and line number (after you make the changes).

Comment: Constructors don't need return types. But yeah, code as posted does not compile.

Comment: @themel right, it's just that foo is usually used for a function name. My bad :)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore yes it did, thank you. I had lots of include circles everywhere!

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon in the line defining class foo is superfluous:

```
class foo : public blah;
```

must read

```
class foo : public blah
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class blah; 

class foo : public blah // <- extra ; here
{ 
    public foo(); 
};
```

What do you mean by "used to work but now doesn't"? Which error message are you getting?

Comment: identifier x is undefined. In the case of Scale() Colour() etc, which are local to gameobject